# How to add Drupal Commerce to an existing Drupal site?

Tags: 7, commerce

I wonder how to add the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module to an existing Drupal installation.

I've had problems with the documentation about this topic that I have looked at so far:

- A video about [Adding Drupal Commerce to Existing Sites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iILniz-Kobk).
- The [Drupal Commerce User Guide](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations).

I've also looked at the available [Community documentation about Drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/node/1007434) and I have installed the required modules. But when I try creating the products I'm having issues.

After following the aforementioned documentation and creating a custom product I get this error when trying to view the newly created product:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property
>   commerce_product. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo()

Any suggestions about how to resolve this error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about requests for tutorials or other online sources.

Comment: This type of questions is expressly reported as off-topic on [What topics can I ask about here?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) If you have a specific problem, then ask a question about that problem. Stack Exchange doesn't aim to be a repository of links.

Comment: With my accepted edit suggestion (as per the "put on hold" suggestion to "edit the question"...), I believe the previous 2 comments no longer apply ... and hence "closing this question" does not seem to me the right thing to do (though I have NOT enough reputation to vote against closing this question ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1: Instructions from the community documentation

You saw the available [community documentation about Drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/node/1007434), where it says (bold markup added here):

> If you're **installing Drupal Commerce on an existing Drupal site** or on a new Drupal site without using Commerce Kickstart, you first need to install the latest packaged release of the following modules: ...

From my quote here, it sounds to me that it "has to be possible" to add Drupal commerce into an existing site.

I wonder however if it'd help to get your error resolved by taking into account this part of the community docu page:

> Installing Drupal Commerce modules
>
> When turning on the sub-modules of Commerce, you will notice that some modules are dependent on other modules. You may wish to turn them on one at a time so as to pinpoint any error messages. This is the order to satisfy dependencies:
>
> - Commerce and Commerce UI
> - Customer and Customer UI
> - Price
> - Line Item and Line Item UI
> - Order and Order UI
> - Checkout, Payment, Product
> - Product Reference
> - Cart and Product Pricing
> - Tax
> - Product UI
> - Tax UI
> - Payment UI

More specific: are you using all these modules? If not, could your error be caused by some dependency as mentioned in the quote above? Alse, does your error remain if you (temporarely) install/enable the modules in the list above that you don't use yet.

If you have all those modules enabled, what happens if (a) you disable them all and (b) re-enable them one at a time (as in the quote above also). It might help to pinpoint the real reason for your error message ...

## Option 2: Use the Commerce Repair module

Other thoughts / approaches / attempts:

- look at [issue # 2312841](https://www.drupal.org/node/2312841), especially [comment # 9](https://www.drupal.org/node/2312841#comment-9603445) in it, and the suggested "[Commerce Repair](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_repair)" module. Does this help to get your error resolved?
- Could it be that you're experiencing the bug as described in the answer to [Error When Create Drupal Commerce Product Display](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26204) ? It refers to the same "[Commerce Repair](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_repair)" module, a module that is "looking for a New maintainer", used in over 1.000 sites. To me it appears as your best possible alternative to consider, Unless you want to start from a fresh install.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it and have installed the required modules. But when I try creating the products I'm having issues, so I was wondering whether anyone would know a more comprehensive tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've approved and added details about the error I'm seeing.

Comment: OK, that's a little progress. Fingers crossed that it helps to get the "hold" removed now ... Let me go digest the new info you added ...

Comment: Hey Pierre, I'd like to thank you for your help. After your post I've uninstalled all modules and installed again and still had the errors, however this time when I run Commerce Repair the fields were fixed and everything worked. Thank you!

Comment: Great news! Thx for letting me know (and 'accepting' this answer of course). So in the end "this" seems to have turned out somehow as "the" docu you were originally looking for, right?